How can I test the 'catch' portion of code in a try-catch, using Mockito, when the 'try' is 'Thread.Sleep()?
I'm using mockito to write test, but I'm really struggling with how to test this specific bit of code:
public void myMethod() {
try {
Thread.sleep(400);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}

A lot of examples online use the example of forcing whatever is in the try to throw an error - but everything I've looked at yells 'don't mock a Thread'
Is there a way I can force the code to be interrupted using Thread.interrupt() or similar?
I did start to try and use a spy:
Thread threadSpy = spy(new Thread());
threadSpy.interrupt();
assertThatExceptionOfType(RuntimeException.class);

but I can see that this isn't actually causing the thread in myMethod to interrupt, so isn't actually testing that bit of code.

Is this practical or theoretical question? Because answer will be different.

Somebody has clearly gone completely and utterly off the cliff insane if your dev process implies you must test that line.

@rzwitserloot Well. If that line got in production code you can expect anything.

@talexmovedtoCodidact practically I would like to know how to do it - but I think the fact that I can't think of a way to do it suggests I should probably try and understand theoretically how you would too.

@rzwitserloot I'm playing around with testing and trying to understand how I would do it - whilst understanding that it's not best practise, or something that should be in prod code.

@CodingAllTheTime3 If you really want you can start another thread, run that code in it, and call interupt on it.

@talexmovedtoCodidact That makes sense, thank you.

Here is the test
public class AppTest {
    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void test() {
        AtomicReference<Throwable> reference = new AtomicReference<>();
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                myMethod();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                reference.set(t);
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        thread.interrupt();
        thread.join();
        assertNotNull(reference.get());
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(400);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

Make sure that sleep value is sufficiently large.

I happened to answer a very similar question recently with a much shorter code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79067398/1180351

@RobSpoor you should have close this as duplicate then. Too late, I did it myself :)
